# get current date and time in textView android

Tags: android, date, time, calendar

how to get current date and time in textView android

i am using following code

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("d / MMM / yyyy");
    String strdate1 = sdf1.format(c1.getTime());

    TextView txtdate1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_date_view);
    txtdate1.setText(strdate1);

    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("h : MM : a");
    String strdate2 = sdf2.format(c2.getTime());

    TextView txtdate2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_time_view);
    txtdate2.setText(strdate2);
```

but this is not working below API 23

Comment: Can you post the logcat? These classes are all implemented before API 23

Answer (score 0):

use like this

`SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("d / MMM / yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get hustled with the complication of this code when all you want can be achieved in one line of code

```
String minutes = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());    
textview.setText(minutes);
```